# Сочетанием каких знаков можно сократить напиисание повторяющихся нижеприведенных символов?

Tags: java, c#

Сочетанием каких знаков можно сократить напиисание повторяющихся нижеприведенных символов?
      Console.WriteLine("-------------------------")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int n = 25;
String str = new String('-',n);
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.string(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Спасибо, @Valera!

Answer (score 2):

В java для String нет конструктора c заданием числа повторений символа. На [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4903603/2929220) приведен пример обхода:

```
String repeated = new String(new char[n]).replace("\0", s);
n-число повторений
s-строка, в вашем случае "-"
```

Создается строка на основе массива char, после чего null в массиве заменяется вашим символом.

Так же можно использовать сторонние библиотеки, например, apache-commons

```
System.out.println(StringUtils.repeat("-",4));
```